# Invalid encoding: ISO-8859-1 API for stripe in Laravel

Tags: laravel, stripe-payments

I have a system which a user can upload a zip file which has a link created at the same time to it. When the zip is purchased, it sends the ID of the zip file along with the payment details to Stripe to process then passes back to my site to then allow the user to download the file. However I notice in Stripe's dashboard, the webhook is failing with error Invalid encoding: ISO-8859-1 but the payment processes ok. I have no idea what's going on. I have SSL set up and redirecting with .htaccess, could this be the issue? Sorry not done Stripe before, so if there's any code you would need to help from my side, please let me know what you need and I will share.

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting an error 403? (It will appear above the ISO-8859-1)

I had a very similar issue. If you are getting error 403 that is the key and not the ISO-8859-1.

This means you have inadvertantly blocked one, or more, of stripe's ip addresses.

There are two lists. One is for webhooks you can view here: https://stripe.com/docs/ips

You can search your .htaccess for each ip listed. (This did not work for me as there was a rogue blocked ip somewhere I did not detect)

So what I did was an "allow from" list using ALL of Stripe's Ip's before the "deny from" in the .htaccess file.

Something like this:

```
<Files 403.shtml>
order allow,deny
allow from all
</Files>

#start allow all STRIPE ip's
allow from 13.112.xxx.xxx
allow from 13.115.xxx.xxx
//and so on
#end allow all STRIPE ip's

#start deny ip's
deny from
```

Then save the file and load it to your server.

NOTE: Sometimes when you get IP blocking lists provided on the internet the lists will include the Stripe IPs as Stripe uses Amazon.

ALSO NOTE for other readers: Make sure your "endpoint" accurately relfects either http:// or https:// for your site. In your case it should be https:// unless you have a redirect taking care of that.

Comment: I have the same issue but error 401.